# Used a chemical on my MacBook screen. Now what?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I used [Monster ScreenClean](https://www.monsterstore.com/collections/screenclean/products/ultimate-performance-tv-cleaning-kit) to clean the screen of my MacBook Air. I later read that this will leave a film on the screen, which seems to be the case when holding the screen up against the light.

How can I return my screen to the state it was before using the chemical? (Preferably without purchasing additional or hard-to-obtain products.) Or is my screen permanently ruined?

The printing on the bottle very informatively lists the following ingredients:

1. De-ionized water
2. Proprietary polymers

Comment: It probably depends what the chemical is - which they don't say on that page. You'd probably have to ask the manufacturer, unless it's on the label.

Comment: I've asked the manufacturer for a list. Also updated the link to point to the manufacturer.

Comment: They'd probably be the best source of information for how to get it off too.

Comment: Apple recommends just a light water spritz and a microfiber cloth. I'd turn off the Mac and give it a good polish, it just might do the trick.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Checked the bottle :P

Comment: Probably worth also linking this to the sidebar, for future ref - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268046/can-i-clean-my-macbook-pro-keyboard-with-vodka

Comment: & this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230065/cleaning-my-macbook-pro-retina-leaves-greasy-streaks-across-the-screen

Answer (score 1):

You may have damaged the coating on your MacBook Air Screen.  Chemicals "strip" the protective coating that's applied to the glass.  It's like if you peeled some of the tint on your car window; you can't wipe it back on.

Monster includes a PDF "manual" which is available on their [website's support page](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2808/7920/files/LIT_INT_iclean_warning.pdf).

[image: Monster Screen Clean Warning Label]

> **If the product to be cleaned stipulates "soap and water" cleaning only or
>   recommends that no cleaners be used on your product, do not use this
>   cleaner as a cleaning method**.

As, as pointed out in the comments, [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204172) says to dampen a soft cloth with **water only**.

> To clean the screen on your MacBook, MacBook Pro, or MacBook Air,
>   first shut down the computer and unplug the power adapter. Dampen a
>   soft, lint-free cloth with water only, then use it to clean the
>   computer's screen.

**Bottom Line**

You probably damaged the protective coating.  You may be able to "polish" the streak out by completely removing the protective layer, but this is just conjecture at this point.