# What to do with my screen?

Tags: macbook-pro

As you can see my screen, it gives impression something got scratched on it but that's not the case. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: I dunno, it looks pretty scratched up to me. You may want to edit the photo and mark it up to call out what, specifically, you are referring to.

Comment: Did you try to clean it with anything but soap and water?  See this recent question:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316798/used-a-chemical-on-my-macbook-screen-now-what/316818#316818

Answer (score 1):

What I can see from the photo, it doesn't look like scratches. Instead it looks like the anti-reflective coating is "peeling off". This is a manufacturing defect.

Apple has a program where you can get a free display replacement, if this is indeed the case.

The following laptops are eligible:

• MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2013)
• MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2013)
• MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2013)
• MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2013)
• MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2014)
• MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2014)
• MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2015)
• MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2015)
• MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016)
• MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016)
• MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017)
• MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017)
• MacBook (12-inch, Early 2015)
• MacBook (12-inch, Early 2016)
• MacBook (12-inch, Early 2017)

The program seems to cover them for 4 years from the original purchase date.

You'll need to contact Apple Support to find out if this is really the problem with your laptop, and whether or not it is covered for a free screen replacement.

Comment: My friend said the same but issue is I am in Pakistan.. will try to reach them out. Is there some quick route to reach them? when you say "Screen replacement", is it protector like we use for mobile screens?

Comment: The program is world-wide as far as I know, so there should be no issue about being in Pakistan. The quickest route is probably to call them, and arrange  from there. No by "screen replacement" I mean that the display is replaced with a new, non-defective display. I.e. you have to take it in (or mail it in) for repairs.